# Where to place Clojure Specs?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

If you use Clojure Spec, how do you use it?

Do you tend to put all your specs in one place or distribute them through the "modules" of your program?

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, note the prohibition on questions where "each answer is equally valid". This is much akin to the general consensus on [meta] that best-practice questions are by nature [too broad to fit the format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296542/are-is-it-a-good-practice-questions-off-topic-or-opinion-based) (or opinion-based, which boils down to the same thing).

Comment: (My own preference is to have a dedicated namespace for specs, but that's *preference* / opinion).

Comment: This is an important question of Clojure style. I would like to know what the sensible options are and how to assess their merits according to purpose.

Comment: I prefer this format: `specs.cljc` in the root, and a `specs` subfolder with more specific specs. E.g., `specs/more_specific.cljc`. This leads to nice namespaces: `project.specs` + `project.specs.more-specific`.

Comment: You could rephrase the question as "is it idiomatic to have my specs in place X?" and it sounds less opinion-based, at least to my non-native speaker ears. However, I'm interested in hearing opinions and the reasoning behind them.

Comment: this is a good question for ask.clojure.org